# SQL Server : append string not working if col is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to programatically append some string to `col1`. The below code works only in case `col1` is not empty. If it's empty then after running the code it remains empty. Why?

```
UPDATE 
    table
SET 
    col1 = col1 + ';somestring'
WHERE 
    col2 = rowID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because any operation with `NULL` results in `NULL`. You need to use `ISNULL()` to "transform" your `NULL` values into empty strings:

```
UPDATE 
    table
SET 
    col1 = ISNULL(col1, '') + ';somestring'
WHERE 
    col2 = rowID
```

Comment: That was an easy one, huh? Really appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to solve this.

**First** use `ISNULL`

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(10) -- not initialized (null)

SELECT @var + N'test' -- yields null

-- use ISNULL to fix it
SELECT ISNULL(@var,N'') + N'test' 
GO
```

**Second** disabling the `NULL_YIELDS_NULL` if you have many of this operations.

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(10) -- not initialized (null)

-- you can also disactivate this behaviour for this session
-- This way all null concats will be interpreted as an empty string
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF --disable null yields null for one ore more operations

SELECT @var + N'test'

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON --reenable it, if you don't need it disabled anymore
GO
```